# Convergent sequence of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, examples-counterexamples, absolute-value

> Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be sequence of complex numbers. If $ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n $, then is $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lvert x_n \rvert = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lvert y_n \rvert $? Is the converse true?

Comment: What's $0<z<∞$ for complex $z$?

Comment: For $x_n = 1$ and $y_n = -1$ we have $\lim |x_n| = 1 = \lim |y_n|$ but $\lim x_n = 1 \neq -1 = \lim y_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part use: $|\,|x_n|-|y_n|\,| \leq |x_n-y_n|$ and to see that the second statement is false take $x_n=1,y_n=-1$ for all $n$.